# Удалил триггер на мониторинг RAM.

Tags: zabbix

Удалил триггер на мониторинг RAM:

```
: Свободное дисковое пространство составляет менее 20% от объема Physical Memory на {HOSTNAME}
```

zabbix 3.2

Напишете у кого есть.

Comment: А как звучит ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{PU5:vm.memory.size[free].last(1)}<{PU5:vm.memory.size[total].last(1)}*0.2
```

Вот триггер отвечающий за мониторинг RAM. Если свободной памяти менее 80%, то он срабатывает.